# Activity is slow when the open

Tags: android

I have an activity consisting of 100 edittext. When I run this activity, it gets heavy. He reacts late. Is there a way about it? I will be very pleased if you say the ways of acceleration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the EditTexts placed? If they aren't visible in the same time, for example in a list, you can use `RecyclerView`.

Comment: It all looks at the same time. Settlement patterns are also mixed. There are both horizontal and vertical. I am creating a list. That list is long. I want to move it to electronic media. I want to get rid of the paper pen event. I need it for him.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I'm having trouble visualising it.

Comment: https://imgyukle.com/i/QNeGuY

Comment: This is part of the list. I drew it as an example.

Comment: I'm guessing the user can scroll vertically to access more fields? Is it just text fields or is there more views (labels, buttons, etc)? Is there always only 1 or 3 fields per line?

Comment: think of the rest of the list as above. There will be 2 buttons at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I propose. Use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`, with a custom span lookup so each text field can take a variable number of columns. In this example I made it show a 100 items with 3 full-span fields always followed by 3 fields on one line. Data is stored in `Item` and when a text field is changed, it updates the text in its item.

```java
// I'm using a fragment here, but that doesn't matter.
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Add a few items for testing: 3 full-span fields are followed by 3 fields on one line.
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        items.add(new Item("Item " + i, i % 6 >= 3 ? 3 : 1));
    }

    RecyclerView rcv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rcv.setItemAnimator(null);  // You probably don't need animations.
    rcv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(items));

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 3);
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return items.get(position).spanCount;
        }
    });
    rcv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

private static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private final List<Item> items;

    MyAdapter(List<Item> items) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_edt, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }
}

private static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // I added a label to each text field but you can remove it.
    private TextView label = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
    private EditText textField = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_field);

    private @Nullable Item item;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.text = s.toString();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void bind(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        label.setText(item.text);
        textField.setText(item.text);
    }
}

private static class Item {

    String text;
    final int spanCount;

    Item(String text, int spanCount) {
        this.text = text;
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
    }
}
```

Performance should be a lot better, considering there's always only 20-30 EditTexts being shown at a time, and these are constantly getting recycled when you scroll the list. For the buttons at the bottom, you can add another view type to handle that.

If you have any questions, please let me know.